# "On the steps" vs "at the steps"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Are both grammatical? Different?

Example sentence:

> I entered the station but stopped at/on the steps that led into it.

Comment: *On the steps* means that you are standing upon the steps. *At the steps* means either just above or below the actual steps but not ON them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you said to me that you **are on the steps** it would suggest you are actually standing on one of the steps being referred to. If you said you are **at the steps** it would suggest you are in the vicinity of *the steps*. Furthermore, it would suggest both you and the person you are communicating with understand what steps you are talking about.